# How to Generate incredibly large arrays in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When trying to generate a large array using the following command

```
GENERATE_ARRAY(1467331200, 1530403201, 15)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 GENERATE_ARRAY(1467331200, 1530403201, 15) produced too many elements
```

Is there a way to generate an array of said size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of result elements up to 1048575.

```
Test: bq query --dry_run --nouse_legacy_sq "[replace query below]"
Query: select GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1048575) as test_array;
Output: Query successfully validated. Assuming the tables are not modified, running this query will process 0 bytes of data.

Query: select GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1048576) as test_arr;
Output: GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1048576, 1) produced too many elements
```

There's no mention of this limit in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_array) so I suggest that you either send a documentation feedback on the page or file a feature request to increase the limit or if possible remove the limit.

Possible workaround is to concat the array.
Example: `SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,1048575), GENERATE_ARRAY(1,1048575))...`

Comment: There is a 100MB limit on the size of arrays, as a heads up. The limit on the number of elements produced by `GENERATE_ARRAY` is mostly there to help prevent against accidentally writing heavily CPU-bound queries.